# PHP: Foreach accessing values for improperly indexed array

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

i have an improperly index being provided by an api call as below

```
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [xml] =>  
            [qid] =>1
            [title] => Tile of the question 
            [description] => Description of the question here
        )

    [1] => xml for quetion 1 
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [xml] =>  
            [qid] => 2
            [title] => Updated Question 
            [description] => description changed for edting
        )

    [3] => xml for quetion 2  
)
```

i can access the value in foreach loop but problem is that xml for each question is being set in next index on the loop:

```
foreach ($array as  $key =>$node) {
     $title = $node->title;
     $des = $node->description;
     $qid = $node->qid;
     if($node->xml==''){
         // set xml value here in 1  and 3 index seen as in above output 
      }
    }
```

how can i do that pls advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just try this:

```php
foreach ($array as  $key =>$node) {
    try {
        $title = $node->title;
        $des = $node->description;
        $qid = $node->qid;
        if($node->xml==''){
            $xml = $array[$key + 1];
        }
        echo "Added row with index $key";
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        echo "That was a xml row - The key is $key";
    }
}
```

Comment: $xml = $array[$key + 1]; this  worked, Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're getting the data in "pairs". Index 0 and 1 belong together, 2 and 3, and so on.

If that is true, you can split the data into chunks and process each pair:

```
$chunks = array_chunk($array, 2);
foreach($chunks as $chunk) {
    // $chunk[0] contains object with title, qid, ...
    // $chunk[1] contains "xml for question"
}
```

Comment: that's also a good approach which one is efficient in comparison to the one Advised by @azibom